# Formatting a txt file on python

Tags: python

I would like to know how to display the .txt file I am opening alpahbetically, also how to show in order of scores high to low etc and how to work out an average

```
score= str(score)
class_name = clas + ".txt"
file = open(class_name , "a")
file.write(name)
file.write(" : ")
file.write (score)
file.write("\n")
file.close()
##########################
read = input("Would you like to see your classes previous scores? ")
if read == "yes".lower():
    file = open(class_name,"r")
    lines = file.read()
    file.close()
    print (lines)
else:
    print("The program will now close")
```

The file save the data inputted in the format
Name : Score

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data in a dictionary like this:

```
dataDictionary = {};
for line in openFile.readlines():
    name, score = line.strip().split(': ');
    dataDictionary[name] = score;
```

To show entries by name alphabetically:

```
names = dataDictionary.keys();
names.sort();
for name in names:
    print '%s: %s' % (name, dataDictionary[name]);
```

To show entries by score in increasing order:

```
sortedByScore = sorted(dataDictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]);
for pair in sortedByScore:
    print '%s: %s' % (pair[0], pair[1]);
```

The key is in using the built-in function sorted to sort items in a dictionary by values;

Comment: Would this still save the data so even if the program is closed the data is retained?

Comment: no it wouldn't. for that you would need additional lines of code. but in your initial question you did not mention saving data just how to organize it.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not too large, just load the whole thing into memory as a list of lists and then slice it up however you need. For instance, assuming `class_name` holds the name of your file:

```
with open(class_name, 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    records = [line.split(':') for line in lines]

    # Alphabetize
    alphabetical_records = sorted(records, key=lambda x: x[0])

    # Order by score
    score_ordered_records = sorted(records, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))

    # Take the average:
    import numpy as np
    mean = np.mean([float(x[1]) for x in records])
```

Comment: this comes up with the error Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Comment: It works fine on my machine, could you be more specific about where the error is thrown?

Comment: File "E:\Computing\A453 - Python\Program\Maths.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    records = [line.split(':') for line in lines]
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Comment: Ah, this seems to be some python3 incompatibility. I'm using python2.7, which doesn't throw the error. You'll have to ask someone else what's going on there, as I haven't used python3 much